# Find $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}$ if $z=f(x,y)$ , $u=e^x\cos y$ , $v=e^{-x}\sin y$

Tags: partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation, chain-rule

I don't know how to use the fact that $z=f(x,y)$.

I tried to solve $(x,y)$ in terms of $(u,v)$ and found that $y=\frac{\sin^{-1}(2uv)}{2}$ but can't solve $x$.

Another question: Is $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=\frac{1}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}$ ?

Comment: Is there a typo here? Are you required to compute $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}$? The answer below is correct, but I fail to see any influence in the answer via, what I believe is the whole point of the question which is to use the chain rule for partial derivatives.

Comment: @Bacon is right.  The fact that $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ has no impact.  Is this a typo?

Comment: I checked the question and it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you take $u=e^x \cos y$ and differentiate with respect to $u$, you get
$$
    1 = e^{x} \cos y \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} - e^x \sin y \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}
$$
If you take $v = e^{-x}\sin y$ and differentiate with respect to $u$, you get
$$
    0 = -e^{-x} \cos y \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} - e^{-x} \sin y \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}
$$
This is a system of two equations for the two unknowns $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$.

Can you solve it from here?

Comment: But isn't $v$ depend on $u$ through $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: @MohamedMostafa: not unless $z$ is constant.